# Coredata for getting all the values of a field

Tags: core-data, field

I have an entity ("Settings") and I want to get all the values in just one field ("Status").I am using coredata. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of all values for "Status" across all Settings objects? Do you care about duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

Declare this in .h file:
NSMutableArray *eventArray;

and in .m file

```
- (void)fetchRecords {   
    // Setup the fetch request  
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    // Define our table/entity to use  
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Settings" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]; 

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Status" ascending:YES];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity]; 

    NSError *error; 

    // Get array of results.

    NSMutableArray *theResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy];

    if (!theResults) {  
        // Handle the error.  
        // This is a serious error and should advise the user to restart the application  
    } 

    // Grab unique neighborhoods through NSSet.

    NSSet *uniqueElements = [NSSet setWithArray:[theResults valueForKey:@"Status"]];
    // Dump NSSet uniques into new array.

    NSMutableArray *sortedResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[uniqueElements allObjects]]; 

    for(int i = 0; i < [sortedResults count];i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"%d. %@", i+1, [sortedResults objectAtIndex:i]); 
    }

    // Save our fetched data to an array

    [self setEventArray: sortedResults];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, u can get Array of values:

```
NSFetchRequest *requestSettings = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[requestCodesList setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Setting" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
NSArray *setting = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:requestCodesList error:&error];
if (error) NSLog(@"Failed to executeFetchRequest to data store: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
```

Next, u transfer u array in NSString:

> ComponentsJoinedByString: Constructs
>   and returns an NSString object that is
>   the result of interposing a given
>   separator between the elements of the
>   array.
>
> - (NSString *)componentsJoinedByString:(NSString *)separator
>     code is:

```
NSString *settingChanged = [setting componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

And after u can using this anywhere in u UI (binding, setStringValue e.t.c)